# getting 400 error in laravel by integrating paypal

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I'm trying to integrate Paypal into Laravel. Everything is fine keys etc. But cannot be able to find a proper solution and getting Http response code 400.

Please check the code below:

```php
//create Payer
$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

//create billable items
$item = new Item();
$item->setName(config('settings.business_name')." Booking")
    ->setCurrency(config('settings.default_currency'))
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setPrice($amount_to_charge);


$item_list = new ItemList();
$item_list->setItems(array($item));

//set amount to be charged
$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency(config('settings.default_currency'))
    ->setTotal($amount_to_charge);

//create transaction
$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
    ->setItemList($item_list);

//set redirect URLs
$redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirect_urls->setReturnUrl(route('paymentSuccessful'))
    ->setCancelUrl(route('paymentFailed'));

//set payment
$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('Sale')
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setRedirectUrls(urlencode($redirect_urls))
    ->setTransactions(array($transaction));
$payment->create($this->_api_context);

foreach($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
    if($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
        $redirect_url = $link->getHref();
        break;
    }
}

try {
    //save payment ID and redirect to paypal for payment
    Session::put('paypal_payment_id', $payment->getId());
    if(isset($redirect_url)) {
        return Redirect::away($redirect_url);
    }
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    //set error and redirect to finalize booking
    
    Session::flash('paypal_error', $ex->getMessage());
    return redirect()->route('loadFinalStep');
}
```

Please check the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Log the text of the data sent in your request, and received in the response. There should be an error message with a debug_id , among other things.